# Twiitter TypeAhead not working in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I was trying to use [Twitter Typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) in my application.But it didnt seem to work.I think I am missing some line of code anywhere but cant figure out where I have went wrong.

**Script Reference**

```
<script src="~/plugins/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" id="txtRegNo" data-url="@Url.Action("RegistrationNoSearch")">
```

**JS Code**

```
    $(function () {           
        var RegNoSearch = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
                return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
            },
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: $("#txtRegNo").data("url"),
                filter: function (datas) {
                    return $.map(datas.results, function (data) {
                        return {
                            value: data.RegNo,
                            id: data.RegId
                        };
                    });
                },
                ajax: {
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        param: function () {
                            return $('#txtRegNo').val();
                        }
                    },
                    context: this
                }
            }
        });

        // Initialize the Bloodhound suggestion engine
        RegNoSearch.initialize();

        $('#txtRegNo .typeahead').typeahead({

            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'states',
            displayKey: 'value',
            source: RegNoSearch.ttAdapter()
        });
    });
```

**Controller Code**

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult RegistrationNoSearch(string regNo)
    {
        try
        {
            List<clsRegistrationNoSearch> _lstRegNoSearch = new List<clsRegistrationNoSearch>();
            _lstRegNoSearch = _db.StudentRegistrations
                            .Where(r => r.RegistrationNumber.StartsWith(regNo))
                            .Select(r => new clsRegistrationNoSearch
                            {
                                RegId=r.Id,
                                RegNo=r.RegistrationNumber
                            }).ToList();
            return Json(_lstRegNoSearch, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `Typeahead.js`is not working in my application.Where I have went wrong??

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the console? Is the remote url correct? Do you have to use a `post` to get the data?

Comment: Console is showing no error.Even the get function is not getting hit.

Comment: You are not using a `get` function. You are overriding the default ajax behavior with a `post` instead.  Did you intend to do that?  What version of typeahead.js are you using?

Comment: Sorry not even hitting the `post` function.[TypeAhead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) version is v0.11.1

Comment: Try changing `source: RegNoSearch.ttAdapter()` to `source: RegNoSearch`